# Why are two identical request to /pages fired with every pageload?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above two identical requests are fired to the Occ Endpoints pages (this behaviour appears on every page load), i'd like to understand the purpose behind this behaviour, because there's definetly a thought process behind this doubled payload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a known bug that is being looked at: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/6900